# How do I copy nodes and relationships I set up as a template, and apply new instance info to the copies?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to assign tasks (I'm calling them "todos" because "tasks" is taken) to each new employee of my organization. There are a few events around which the todos are organized, and some of the todos have associated documents.

[image]

Now I need help figuring out how to can a cypher query that will create a new version of each of the todos (along with any related documents) and assign it to the new hire.

Other info: Each new hire has an HR person assigned to them, and for the new instances of each task, the task is "assigned to" the new hire and "assigned_by" the HR person.

Here's some cypher pseudo-code:

```
match(newHire:Person {name:"Jane Doe"})-[:HAS_HR_CONTACT]->(hrContact:Person)
with newHire, hrContact
match(firstDay:MetaEvent {name:"First Day"})<-[:RELEVANT_TO]-(task:ToDo)
optional match (task)-[:HAS_DOCUMENT]->(doc:Document)
with newHire, hrContact, task, doc
//... and now I'm lost
```

What I need to know is how to take the properties of the template ToDo, and copy them to the new instance. Then, if there's a document attached to the template ToDo, I need to attach the same document (no instance or templates here) to the new instance.

I'm guessing this will use paths and unwind and I've looked for tutorials, but I'm not having much luck. Any help, much appreciated.

Last of all, I'm using neo4j 2.2.9, but I can upgrade that if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to copy the template for each new-hire. Instead, each new hire can have a relationship to each (existing) `ToDo` node that is relevant to him/her. If you have to store any person-specific piece of info for each `ToDo`, you can store it in a property of the relationship.

For instance:

```
MATCH (newHire:Person {name:"Jane Doe"})
MATCH (:MetaEvent {name:"First Day"})<-[:RELEVANT_TO]-(task:ToDo)
CREATE (newHire)-[:HAS_TO_DO {time_assigned: timestamp()}]->(task);
```

In this example, I store in each `HAS_TO_DO` relationship the time at which the related task was assigned. Notice that there is no need to do anything explicitly with the optional documents.

Comment: That's a good idea, and one I toyed with earlier. I should have mentioned in my question, that I hope to use these ToDos again in other contexts, and at that point they may have more than one person assigned to them. In that context, it will make more sense to have data like status="closed" on the individual tasks rather than the (potentially) multiple relationships.

Answer (score 0):

I did this. It works because I use WITH to package up any relationships the original ToDos have with documents, and then collect those todos and their documents in another collection. Then it's pretty simple to use unwind and/or foreach to loop through everything. It's useful to use the {} notation when creating a collection.

```
// get the template tasks associated with the event
MATCH (e:MetaEvent {name:"First Day"})<-[:RELEVANT_TO]-(td:ToDo)
// If they have documents, get those too
OPTIONAL MATCH (td)-[docRel:HAS_DOCUMENT]->(d:Document) 
// get the event, and todos, and collect the documents
WITH e, td, collect(d) as documents
// get the event and collect the tasks along with any documents
WITH e, collect ({todo:td, taskDocs:documents}) as tasks
// match the person
MATCH (newHire:Person {name:"John Doe"})-[:HAS_HR_GENERALIST]->(generalist:Person)
// not sure you need this ...
WITH e, newHire, generalist, tasks
// use unwind to loop through all the collected tasks
UNWIND tasks as task
// create a new copy of each task and set any particular properties
CREATE (ntd:ToDo {title:task.todo.title})
SET ntd.event = e.name
// for any document attached to the original template todo, create a similar relationship with the new todo (ntd)
FOREACH(d in task.taskDocs |
    MERGE (ntd)-[:HAS_DOCUMENT]->(d)
)
// Finally ... assign the new todo to the people it needs to be attached to
merge (generalist)<-[:ASSIGNED_BY]-(ntd)-[:ASSIGNED_TO]->(newHire)
```